# Android Studio gradle build failed : could not find bundletools.jar(com.android.tools.build:bundletools:010-alpha01)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, build

I have used a new update of my coworker. and he changed the build.gradle file.
But my IDE keeps telling me:
Gradle sync failed: Could not find bundletool.jar (com.android.tools.build:bundletool:0.1.0-alpha01).
Searched in the following locations:
https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/bundletool/0.1.0-alpha01/bundletool-0.1.0-alpha01.jar

and here is my gradle file

```
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    jcenter()
    google()
    mavenCentral()
}
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
    }
}
```

I have tried Setting -> Gradle -> Use default gradle wrapper and unmark Offline work

Comment: what about `alpha02`

Comment: where to set this alpha02?

Comment: `bundletool:0.1.0-alpha02`

Answer (score 17):

The fix is to put `google()` above `jcenter()` in your repository list in `gradle`.

Comment: I tried this and still have the same problem. But I solved the problem by changing com.android.tools.build:gradle back to 3.0.1 , anyway thanks for helping.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I put `jcenter()` in first of repository's list in gradle file.It fixed the problem

```
repositories {
       jcenter()
        google()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In "*gradle-wrapper.properties*":

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.1.1-all.zip
```

Then sync Gradle project.

Answer (score -1):

Change classpath to >> **'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'**
it's work for me !