# IntelliJ IDEA/Android Studio/VS Code cannot download bundletools for Gradle

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, visual-studio-code

To develop a Flutter app I have installed both Android Studio, IntelliJ IDEA and VS Code on my Windows 10 machine.

When I try to run the project (the sample code created by Android Studio) I get the following error:

```
 problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not find bundletool-0.14.0.jar (com.android.tools.build:bundletool:0.14.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/bundletool/0.14.0/bundletool-0.14.0.jar
```

However, I clicked on the link in the error message and downloaded `bundletool-0.14.0.jar` without any issue.

So, why the IDE cannot download it?

And now that I have downloaded the file manually, where I should put it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Studio gradle build failed : could not find bundletools.jar(com.android.tools.build:bundletools:010-alpha01)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50563504/android-studio-gradle-build-failed-could-not-find-bundletools-jarcom-android)

Comment: Thanks. I checked that (and some other) before posting this. None of those solutions solved my problem so I had to reinstall everything.