# Android studio gradle build failed: Could not find bundletool-1.11.4.jar

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, build

I tried solutions mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50563504/android-studio-gradle-build-failed-could-not-find-bundletools-jarcom-android). Non of them worked.

This is the error I get:

```
A problem occurred configuring root project 'My ApplicationTst'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not find bundletool-1.11.4.jar (com.android.tools.build:bundletool:1.11.4).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/bundletool/1.11.4/bundletool-1.11.4.jar

Possible solution:
 - Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html
```

I also downloaded the file from browser and used the flatDir and maven local repository but it didn't work either. What can I do? what is the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up deleting the root .gradle folder in my user folder (in mac) and then resync the project.
The problem is mostly due to sanctions in Iran internet.
If you are using windows, maybe find where else the gradle cash folders are.

Comment: The cache folder is about 9G and includes different versions of gradle. Should I delete and redownload everything? or is there a specific folder I have to delete?